# Get language translation in xml from external json file

Tags: android, json, translation

As a part of an app that I am developing there is request that it has to  download JSON file that contains language translation that needs to be used in app instead of strings.xml file that is commonly used because this way any translation in app can be changed by updating external JSON file on some web portal and it avoid the need to make new build every time you want to change language translation.

I've already done this, and everything is working fine in a following way:
For example If I have button in xml once the activity starts I can reference the button and set the it's text from JSON that I've downloaded at the startup.

```
btnLogin = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

// reads translation from json that is stored in external application directory
btnLogin.setText(ResourceManager.getString("btnLogin"));
```

But my question is is there any way that I can avoid setting this text always from activity, can I somehow do it from XML file where this button is defined?

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="{ResourceManager.getString("btnLogin")}"/>
```

Is there any possibility that let's me call some function from xml and bind it's result to text attribute or is there any other way which avoids referencing all buttons/textviews and other controls from activity and setting text from there?

Comment: You can do something like [Implementing Dynamic Localization on Android](https://betterprogramming.pub/dynamic-localization-on-android-be0b69f73be4)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding getResources() in you Application class and then
returning an extended version of Resources.

Ok, I tried this and it seemed to work for most of the resources in my xml file.
You may have to override this in more than one place. I just overrode it inside my Application class.

```
private MyResources resources;

@Override
public Resources getResources() {
    if (resources == null) {
        resources = new MyResources(super.getResources());
    }
    return resources;
}

class MyResources extends Resources {


    public MyResources(Resources resource) {
        super(resource.getAssets(), resource.getDisplayMetrics(), resource.getConfiguration());
    }

    public String getString(int resId) {
        return "Bob";  // Use your ResourceManger here
    }
}
```

This worked for me..

Comment: ResourceManager class is the class I created for parsing and getting language translation from JSON file, it has nothing to do with android resources. I am wondering if there is a way to invoke some function call from xml atrribute (android:text="executeFunction("translationKey")") which would return some value and set it as a text and with this I would avoid additional code from every activity where I would have to reference every control and set it's translation.

Comment: Yes, but the xml is resolved through the Resources class. So if you extend that class and can get the system to use your extended version then you can override the methods in resources and call your class functions instead?

Comment: Never mind, it looks like getString is final on the Resources class.

Comment: Changed this to a working code example. I tried it on an application and it seemed to replace most of the strings in the application with "Bob". I'm assuming you have some way to get from resId to your JSON value.

Comment: How can I invoke this call to getString from xml, and it has only int resId parameter that I have no use of since I have some other String keys for language translation value in my JSON file?